# How to hide database password in connectionString, alternative to aspnet_regiis.exe

Tags: asp.net, connection-string, web-config

I have an asp.net web application where its web server is located at client site. We have multiple client sites with their own web server. The clients have full access to the web server, including IIS. Currently, the database password (in the connection string) is stored in web.config and is unencrypted. I know, I know, the biggest and the most embarrassing blunder in my work history.

Therefore, now I want to hide at least the password, or better yet the connection string. I've googled and read about `aspnet_regiis.exe`. I believe `aspnet_regiis.exe` is not the best option for my case given the client/user has full access to the IIS, thus, with some googling, they can easily decrypt the connection string.

While there is an option to programmatically build the connection string, it requires too much changes on my current code. Most of my web pages use datasource that rely on the connection string. If I were to programmatically build the connection string, I will need to dynamically initialize the datasource. This is all well except I will lose the ViewState data and user input everytime there is a postback. I can manually persists the user input, but I still couldn't 100% emulate the data from ViewState, not to mention the huge changes needed to be done to the current code.

Hence I'm looking for a way to hide the password or move the connectionString somewhere where it can be hidden.

Please help. Thank you.

By the way, Windows Authentication is not an option.